# Flask & mod_wsgi post request executing get function

Tags: python, flask, mod-wsgi

I have a Flask web app with two functions for handling POST and GET requests, separately, like:

```
@app.route("/", methods=["POST"])
def function1():
    ...
```

and another function that handles get requests, like:

```
@app.route("/", methods=["GET"])
def function2():
    ...
```

On Apache, I have a virtualhost configured to forward requests to mod_wsgi.
However, for either POST or GET request to Apache, function2 gets executed.

What am I missing?

Comment: We need more details about the Apache server config and mod_wsgi, the example is not enough to reproduce the issue. (and how do you test GET or POST ? )

Comment: For sending post requests, I'm using python requests module, for get requests I usually use browser. What configuration would be helpful to you?

Comment: What response do you get? 404, 500? Is that from Apache, or your Python application? Have you tried a WSGI hello world without Flask to see if your server configuration is correct?

Comment: I'm getting 200. Yes, I have a flask app working with mod_wsgi normally for GET requests... However, POST requests to Apache seems to reach Flask as GET.

Comment: I figured it out. The endpoint for post via mod_wsgi requires a trailing slash! For running the web app on dev flask server that's not required however, going through Apache and mod_wsgi it is.

Answer (score 0):

You trying to do something like this?

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def behavior():
    if flask.request.method == 'POST':
        function2()
    elif flask.request.method == 'GET':
        function1()
    else:
        pass
```